# What's new in the C++11 preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

This image from Microsoft implies that, on the roadmap to support for C++14, there is work to be done in Visual Studio to support the C++11 preprocessor:

[image: Conformance roadmap: The road to C++14 ("wave"????)]

What changes does this involve?

Comment: for Windows users there is also LLVM, still in beta at the moment, but it's available along with a Visual Studio plugin http://llvm.org/builds/

Comment: From this chart you can not deduce that anything has changed in the preprocessor from C++03 to C++11. It only says that their current preprocessor is not C++11 conformant.

Comment: @Alex: That's an answer, which I already gave, an hour ago... :)

Comment: Ouch... Only read the title, saw the image, added a comment, ... should have read the answer :-) Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's new in the C++11 preprocessor?

C++03 used the C90 preprocessor, and C++11 added features from the C99 preprocessor on top of that. Those added features are:

- arithmetic with extended integer types;
- mixed string literal concatenation;
- `_Pragma` operator;
- variadic macros and empty macro arguments.

> What changes does this involve?

Even in Visual Studio per this chart, **not many**, since Microsoft don't actually have to implement the C11 changes to gain C++11 compliance. In implying this, the chart could be deemed misleading; evidently they *are* targetting some C11 support for C++14 but, then again, [I can't see that C11 changes much anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29).

However, to achieve compliance with C++11, according to the chart Microsoft *do* need to bring themselves up to proper C99 standards.